Create a raster where each cell represents the distance to the shoreline in QGIS
I have a polygon representing a boundary of a lake. I want to create a raster where each cell inside the lake represents the distance to its shoreline using QGIS.
I have tried rasterizing the polygon and using the proximity (raster distance) tool in QGIS with no success. How might you solve this problem?


Make sure your data is in a projected coordinate system so the distance units aren't in degrees.

I have a lake with islands, remove them with Delete holes. You dont have to do this if you want to inklude islands as land.
Boundary to extract the shoreline
Rasterize the shoreline. A fixed value to burn=1. Start with a low resolution or proximity can be very slow.
Proximity. target pixels = 1. Distance units = georeferenced coordinates
Clip the proximity by the delete hole output, or the input polygon layer.

The furthest distance from the shoreline is ~6400 meters:

